# JavaScript Object - Split() method + '\n'

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch, javascript-objects

I reached 'fetch' method...

A simple question (complicated for me) ...
How to use 'fetch()' method, 'split()' and '\ n' together?

I will show you an example (i am here to learn and master some skills and i am not ashamed to ask):

**I need to read and print the following data using the 'fetch' method:**

from the following link 'https://v-dresevic.github.io/Advanced-JavaScript-Programming/data/students.txt' - it is necessary to read the data and print them on the page.

*And that is quite clear to me! I managed to do that!*

code: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLhrq.png)

my result (wrong result): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQynP.png)

correct result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiL8Q.png)

**My question is:**
After reading the data from the file, I have to parse them and create Student objects based on them.
Parsing can be done using the split () method of the String object.
It is best to divide the read text by line breaks, specifying "\ n" for the split () method parameter.

*thanks in advance :)*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Don't post code as an image.

Comment: Unclear how showing the students in the textarea with extra lines relates to creating student objects with the data. If you need to create them in student objects, you know that [0+n] is the name, [1+n] is the address, [2+n] is the phone, and [3+n] is the subject. Simple loop by 4 and you can create the student object after the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a fast example of parsing your data to an array of objects as i think this is the only thing you ask here, from there you can loop that array and display the object as you need.

```js
const url =
  "https://v-dresevic.github.io/Advanced-JavaScript-Programming/data/students.txt";
let result = fetch(url)
  .then((r) => r.text())
  .then(process);
function process(result) {
  const linesDescription = ["Name", "Address", "Phone", "Course"];
  const array = [];
  let obj = {};
  var lines = result.split("\n");
  let x = 0;
  for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
    obj[linesDescription[x]] = lines[line].trim();
    x++;
    if (x >= linesDescription.length) {
      array.push(obj);
      x = 0;
      obj = {};
    }
  };
  console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: thank so much too!!!
Thank you for your understanding (i am a beginner)!
You helped me a lot!